# Adobe Air version > 2.6 port

Tags: linux, adobe-flash

I just want to know if anybody is aware of a port of Adobe Air Runtime > 2.6.

Adobe officially discontinued support of air technology for Linux desktop after releasing 2.6 and I got some .air app updates that require version 2.7 or 3.0.